How to get detailed error messages. Include table & column names & records. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int
I have an old, large (more than 140 lines), and complicated SQL query. It is joining many tables and has detailed WHERE conditions with values and a detailed GROUP BY part.
Query Structure
SELECT 
    H.C1
    H.C2
    H.C3
    D.C1
    D.C2
    D.C3
    C.C1
    C.C2
    F.C1
    F.C2
    F.C3

FROM TBL1 H
    LEFT JOIN TBL2 D ON D.WH_ID = H.WH_ID
    LEFT JOIN TBL3 C ON H.CUST_ID = C.ID
    LEFT JOIN TBL4 F ON H.RECEIPT_ID = F.ID 
    AND H.CUST_ID = F.CUST_ID

WHERE 
    DETAILED WHERE CONDITIONS

GROUP BY 
    GROUP COLUMNS

ORDER BY 
    ORDER BY COLUMNS

Error message
It gives
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

Completion time: 2024-09-03T09:41:07.2716887+03:00


It is a superficial error messages, for which the specific table and column or the specific where condition the error is related to is an unknown.
Moving step by step, I solved the problem, but the SQL Server Engine knows the table and column name that are related to the problem. Why doesn't it give this info in the error message?
Using Catch Block
BEGIN TRY

    SELECT 
        H.C1
        H.C2
        H.C3
        D.C1
        D.C2
        D.C3
        C.C1
        C.C2
        F.C1
        F.C2
        F.C3

    FROM TBL1 H
        LEFT JOIN TBL2 D ON D.WH_ID = H.WH_ID
        LEFT JOIN TBL3 C ON H.CUST_ID = C.ID
        LEFT JOIN TBL4 F ON H.RECEIPT_ID = F.ID 
        AND H.CUST_ID = F.CUST_ID

    WHERE 
        DETAILED WHERE CONDITIONS

    GROUP BY 
        GROUP COLUMNS

    ORDER BY 
        ORDER BY COLUMNS

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
         ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
        ,ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine      
END CATCH;
GO

I tried to get detailed error messages with a Catch block but the result was the same.
Is it possible to configure SQL Server (may be with trace flags) or SSMS to give a detailed error messages, including related tables and columns?


The reason these error messages are suppressed is because giving away table and column names is useful information to the attacker if your database is being attacked by SQL Injection or some other method. I am not aware of a way to get a detailed error message apart from in the case of string truncation errors
where you can use the following syntax (SQL 2019 +, there is a trace flag (460) for SQL 2016+)
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION
SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;

@Mo64 thanks a lot. It is a valuable info. After your message I looked the page Trace Flags and used in query with  OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460, QUERYTRACEON 4199); the error message didnt changed but it covers many queries.  In my query the source of error is in the Where condition.

This is a different message I think
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int."
